# How to receive key input without requiring ENTER?

Tags: c++

```
i=0;
while(i<=20)
{
    nullchoice:
    system("CLS");
    //Advanced Information
    cout << "Your Statistics: " << endl;
    cout << endl << endl;
    cout << "   1  Strength: " << str << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "   2  Vitality: " << vit << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "   3  Agility: " << agi << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "   4  Thaumaturgy: " << tha << endl;
    cout << endl << endl;
    cout << "Points Remaining: " << lvlskills << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Enter the number of the skill you wish to increase: ";

    //Applying points to skill attributes

    if(i<=19)
    {
          cin >> input;

          if(input==1)
                str+=1;
          else if(input==2)
               vit+=1;
          else if(input==3)
               agi+=1;
          else if(input==4)
               tha+=1;
          else
               goto nullchoice;

         lvlskills-=1; 
    }    
    i++;
    cout << endl << endl;                     
}
```

So essentially, I am creating a game in C++, a text-based RPG. It's fairly basic, with stats (Strength, Vitality, etc.) you might expect from such a game. In the beginning, as shown here, the player is allowed to distribute some points to skills they choose.

Here's where the problem arises. Right now, the player must enter a number (1, 2, 3, or 4. If it's none of these numbers it will goto the nullchoice), then press ENTER. It's unwieldy and just plain wrong to have the player do this, so is there any simple way that I can code it so they **only** have to press the number?

I'd imagine I would use this very much throughout the rest of my game. Thanks for reading!

Comment: A fairly portable solution is to use the Curses library.

Comment: What OS do you want this for?

Comment: This is for Microsoft Windows

Comment: No, this is not a duplicate thread. The others are covering how to receive button input (getch, cin.get, pause >> nul, etc). So if I were to press "S" it would move on and if I were to press "R" it would do the same thing. What I need is a conditional statement, so that the program can distinguish between "R" and "S."

Comment: The answers in the other questions solve your keyboard input problem. You have to use your own brain as well to use the gathered input the way you need it.

Comment: Duplicate of many questions relating to unbuffered console input, (e.g) conio or curses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to store the input and compare it to the required case. Put a think on it...

```
do
{
    system("CLS");
    //Advanced Information
    cout << "Your Statistics: " << endl;
    cout << endl << endl;
    cout << "   1  Strength: " << str << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "   2  Vitality: " << vit << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "   3  Agility: " << agi << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "   4  Thaumaturgy: " << tha << endl;
    cout << endl << endl;
    cout << "Points Remaining: " << lvlskills << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Enter the number of the skill you wish to increase: ";

    //Applying points to skill attributes
          char input;
          switch(input=getch()){
              case '1':
                str+=1;
                lvlskills-=1;
                break;
          case '2':
               vit+=1;
               lvlskills-=1;
               break;
          case '3':
               agi+=1;
               lvlskills-=1;
               break;
          case '4':
               tha+=1;
               lvlskills-=1;
         } 
    cout << endl << endl;                     
} while(lvlskills>0);
```

Avoid `goto` in your code while you can solve it by other options. It's a good practice..

Comment: This still requires the user to hit enter.

Comment: Nope.. It doesn't.. It's tested...